# how to write if condition for multpile queries like

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, or-condition

I have 3 queries like

```
$q1 = select email from tbl students
$q2 = select email from tbl corporates
$q3 = select email from tbl institutes
```

i want check to all 3 tables if email count is zero from all above then only do proceed like that,,
 can i write like this:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($q1) || mysqli_num_rows($q2)  || mysqli_num_rows($q3) ==0){
proceed to process. 
}else{
do nothing
}
```

My question is it a correct way to approach or anything is better left which i need to learn.

Comment: If you require all to have non-zero length, those logical ors should be ands shouldn't they?

Comment: yeah i think i need `&`..Because if email is not present in 3 table ,then only do the process..  else do nothing so i need to give `&` ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use & instead of || and also check rows count for each of your mysql object

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($q1) == 0 && mysqli_num_rows($q2) == 0 && mysqli_num_rows($q3) ==0){
    //proceed to process. 
} else {
    //do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should execute those queries first so you will have:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$q1 = "select email from tbl students";
$q2 = "select email from tbl corporates";
$q3 = "select email from tbl institutes";

$db_q1 = mysqli_query($db, $q1);
$db_q2 = mysqli_query($db, $q2);
$db_q3 = mysqli_query($db, $q3);

if(mysqli_num_rows($db_q1) == 0 && mysqli_num_rows($db_q2) == 0 && mysqli_num_rows($db_q3) == 0) {
proceed to process. 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try can do easier using  `mysqli_multi_query()`

`$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");// Check connection`

`if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {`

```
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
```

}

```
$sql = select email from tbl students";
$sql .= select email from tbl corporates";
$sql .= "select email from tbl institutes";   

// Execute multi query   

if (mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql)){     

do{   // Store first result set   

    if ($result=mysqli_store_result($con)) {  // Fetch one and one row

       if (mysqli_fetch_row($result) == 0)  {    

           //your code here
    }  
 }
```

`}`